# IGrouping <int, Customer> does not contain a definition for Points etc

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to group these, making the largest value of 'Points' displayed first but its giving me this error:

> `IGrouping <int, Customer>` does not contain a definition for Points, and no extension method Points accepting a first argument of type `IGrouping <int, Customer>` could be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Any help with this? Thank you..

```
Customer result = db.Customer
            .GroupBy(i => i.ID)
            .OrderBy(i => i.Points)
            .SelectMany(g => g);



//From Customer.cs
partial class Customer : Person
{
    public int Points { get; set; }
}

//Note: ID is inherited from the abstract Person class
```

Comment: Please show your `Customer` model. Note that each grouping will contain a `Key` (`i.ID`) to a _list of_ customers (`IEnumerable<Customer>`).

Comment: Will do, give a sec to update the post.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this grouping? Or, better yet, what are you trying to achieve overall? Can you show some sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: Displaying the Customers with the highest ammount of points first.

Comment: Do you `Sum` the points? (I'm assuming you have multiple `Customer` objects with the same `ID` because you're grouping them)

Comment: Ok so, I have multiple customer objects with different values in a List. I am trying to display them with the customer having the highest points displayed first, like a scoreboard.

Comment: If my answer doesn't solve your problem, let me know more details and I'll take another look.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you just want something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> result = db.Customer
    .OrderByDescending(i => i.Points);
```

You only need `GroupBy` if you have multiple items with the same key (`ID`).